# Keyword not supported: 'userÃ‚Â id'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have developed a web application in .Net Core 3.1 (Web API) using Entity Framework 3.1, Angular 10.0 and SQL Server as database.

I have followed code first approach and everything was fine until I deployed my app to IIS on a virtual machine. When I am trying to login to my app for the first time noticed the below error response in the chrome developer console while connecting with my database -

[image: Connection Error in chrome response]

**AppSettings.json -**

```js
{
  "AppSettings" : {
    "Token" : "******"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=datingapp;User Id=appuser;Password=*****"
  },
  
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
}
```

UPDATE : Similar error from postman as well.

Please advise what is wrong with my connection string or could it be something else ?

Thank you

Comment: No, the OP should **not** provide us with their real password, @noobprogrammer , that is a huge security risk. Also, supplying a username and password and using a trusted connection are complete opposites; they are different authentication methods. The former is for SQL Authentication and the latter for Windows Authentication. It's one or the other, not both. If you want to supply a username and password for a Windows Account you have to use impersonation, and then a trusted connection; a very different approach.

Comment: Make sure your appsettings.json file is saved in UTF8 format

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks for the suggestion, but this file is already in UTF8 format. I just cross checked.